# Community Edition Creating a blank app Limitation?

Tags: c#, uwp, vs-community-edition

I am following along a book that asks me to create a "Blank App" project in Visual Studio.

I choose the "Blank App" template in the following path, when creating new project:
Installed -> Visual C# -> Windows -> Universal

I have the community edition.

Double click on the MainPage.xaml file in solution explorer

I get the following error:

> Deployment of package
>   e109a48f-03e8-4942-9834-3d62008a21f8_1.0.0.0_x86_NorthAmerica_8wekyb3d8bbwe
>   with package origin Unsigned failed because no valid license or
>   sideloading policy could be applied. A developer license
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=233074) or enterprise
>   sideloading configuration
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231020) may be required.

How do I get this to work?
I found that community edition is limited, but this particular thing that I am trying to do is not listed as a documented limitation.
Here is the article I found on it:
http://artica-proxy.com/difference-between-the-community-edition-and-the-entreprise-edition/

Comment: Check if you Enabled Developer Mode on Windows configuration.

Answer (score 2):

From your start menu open "Settings" and go to "Update & Security" -> "For Developers" and check "Developer Mode".

Comment: so are you saying that once i do this, then I apply updates to visual studio, it will add the missing component it needs to open the project (in this case, it is Universal Windows Platform)

Comment: good tip, thanks.  but the answer that helped me is posted on bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Add\Remove programs
Go to Visual Studio.net
Select Modify
Visual Studio Installation will pop up with Repair and Modify Options.
Select Modify.

Answer (score 0):

The UWP XAML designer in Visual Studio actually installs an invisible app to your computer to work. If you didn't turn on developer mode in computer's Settings -> Update and Security -> For Developers, Visual Studio can't install the app to your computer, and you can't use the XAML designer. If you turned on developer mode can click the green triangle to start debugging, the XAML designer should work.